# Interpretation of coefficients in fractional response (probit) model

Tags: interpretation, stata, percentage, probit, marginal-effect

I am learning about the estimation of fractional response models (those with a lower and upper bound, say 0 to 1), using Stata. I came across [this example on the Stata page](https://www.stata.com/features/overview/fractional-outcome-models/), which I'm copy-pasting below for simplicity. I have 3 questions regarding the interpretation of coefficients, and any help is much appreciated.

*"We are going to analyze an air-pollution index that is scaled 0 to 1, inclusive (...)
We model pollution as determined by the number of older, pollution-producing cars per capita; percentage of output due to industry; and annual rainfall. We use probit. We type:"*

```
. fracreg probit pollution oldcars rainfall industrial

Iteration 0:   log pseudolikelihood = -1001.8481
Iteration 1:   log pseudolikelihood = -806.74595
Iteration 2:   log pseudolikelihood = -806.55309
Iteration 3:   log pseudolikelihood = -806.55309

Fractional probit regression                            Number of obs =  1,234
                                                        Wald chi2(3)  = 116.91
                                                        Prob > chi2   = 0.0000
Log pseudolikelihood = -806.55309                       Pseudo R2     = 0.0060

                                   Robust
   pollution         Coefficient  std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
     oldcars           .7689171   .1748695     4.40   0.000     .4261791    1.111655
    rainfall          -.3165829   .0350128    -9.04   0.000    -.3852067   -.2479592
  industrial           .2295972    .053877     4.26   0.000     .1240002    .3351942
       _cons          -.3840791   .0393275    -9.77   0.000    -.4611596   -.3069986
```

*"(...) `margins` will make interpreting our results easier. We can ask margins to report elasticities, which is to say, the percentage change in pollution for a 1% change in the covariate:"*

```
. margins, dyex(_all)

Average marginal effects                                 Number of obs = 1,234
Model VCE: Robust

Expression: Conditional mean of pollution, predict()
dy/ex wrt:  oldcars rainfall industrial

                                Delta-method
                          dy/ex   std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
     oldcars           .0411578   .0093973     4.38   0.000     .0227393    .0595763
    rainfall          -.0581577   .0062469    -9.31   0.000    -.0704014   -.0459139
  industrial           .0347474   .0081857     4.24   0.000     .0187037     .050791
```

**Question 1:**
The page explains that we can state that *"a 1% increase of older cars per capita increases pollution by 0.041"*. But can we also say that a 10% increase of older cars per capita increases pollution by $10 \times 0.041=0.41$? Or more generally, can I multiply the elasticity by any number X (say, X = the standard deviation of the variable older cars per capita) and claim that this is the effect on pollution of an increase of X% in older cars per capita?

**Question 2:**
I am also confused by the comment in that page regarding the use of `dyex` vs `eyex`: *"we typed dyex(), not eyex(). The dependent variable is already a proportion and so is already on a percentage scale. We just need its change, not its percentage change."*
Wouldn't it be more appropriate to talk about percentage points instead of percentages, if we are using `dyex`?

**Question 3:**
Would the answer to question 1 change depending on whether `dyex` or `eyex` was used?

Thanks!